# What are the differences between sysfillrect.c and cfbfillrect.c?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, framebuffer

There are two implementations in Linux kernel for generic fillrect. It seems the differences are minor so why do I have both?

The same holds for `copyarea` and `imageblit` there is a `cfb` and a `sys fb` versions, why that?